# Hive On Spark: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

When I ran a query on hive console in debug mode, I got an error as listed below. I'm using hive-1.2.1 and spark 1.5.1; I checked the hive-exec jar, which has the class definition `org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job` .

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/spark/client/Job
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:136)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:115)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:656)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:99)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:507)
    at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:776)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.KryoMessageCodec.decode(KryoMessageCodec.java:96)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec$1.decode(ByteToMessageCodec.java:42)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    ... 15 more*
```

And finally the query fails with:

> "ERROR spark.SparkTask: Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'java.lang.IllegalStateException(RPC channel is closed.)'"*

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have the hivecontext on the spark cluster?

Comment: @eliasah, I have the hiveContext on spark. The query works fine on spark-sql but not on hive-on-spark

Comment: This issue was solved by moving to spark 1.3.0 version and rebuilding it without hive.

Comment: Actually I still have the problem, and I have Spark 1.6.0 with Hive 1.2.1

Answer (score 1):

In hive-1.2.1 pom.xml, the spark.version is 1.3.1

So, The easy way is dowload a spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop from spark.apache.org.

then, add it's path to hive-site.xml like:

```
<property>
  <name>spark.home</name>
  <value>/path/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4</value>
</property>
```